# Cannot sort a Generic Dictionary (by Key) in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I cannot get the loop over a SORTED collection to work with a Generic Dictionary.

Obviously, I'm trying to get:

```
11, Wisconsin
21, Virginia
31, North Carolina
41, Alaska
```

But no go with the 2 different attempts below.

```
$myGenericDictionary = New-Object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[[int],[string]]'

$myGenericDictionary.Add(21, "Virginia")
$myGenericDictionary.Add(31, "North Carolina")
$myGenericDictionary.Add(41, "Alaska")
$myGenericDictionary.Add(11, "Wisconsin")

foreach ($item in $myGenericDictionary.Keys.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Key)
{
    #Write-Output $item.GetType().FullName 
    #$item.PSObject.Properties
    #[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[[int],[string]]] $currentKvp = $item
    Write-Output $item
    [int]$currentKey = $item
    [string]$currentValue = $myGenericDictionary[$currentKey]

    WriteDebugMsg ("Trying to Order These By Key (using GetEnumerator) .   Key:" + $currentKey + ", Value:" + $currentValue)
}


$sortedMyGenericDictionary = New-Object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[[int],[string]]'
$sortedMyGenericDictionary = $myGenericDictionary | Sort-Object -Property Key

foreach ($item in $sortedMyGenericDictionary.Keys)
{
    Write-Output $item
    [int]$currentKey = $item
    [string]$currentValue = $myGenericDictionary[$currentKey]

    WriteDebugMsg ("Trying to Order These By Key (using a separate collection).   Key:" + $currentKey + ", Value:" + $currentValue)
}
```

Comment: `$d.Keys.GetEnumerator()` - this returns the *keys* (sequence of ints here, and integers have no 'Key' property), not the KeyValuePairs .. might want to use `$d.GetEnumerator()` so that the *key-value pairs* can be sorted.

Comment: Gaaaaaaa!  That was it.  Thanks.

Comment: Cool, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user2864740

```
foreach ($item in $myGenericDictionary.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Key) #change here
{
    Write-Output $item
    [int]$currentKey = $item.Key #change here
    [string]$currentValue = $myGenericDictionary[$currentKey]

    WriteDebugMsg ("Trying to Order These By Key (using GetEnumerator) .   Key:" + $currentKey + ", Value:" + $currentValue)
}
```